# Concatenate strings instead of using a stack of TextBlocks

Tags: .net, wpf, datatemplate

I want to show a list of Customer objects in a WPF ItemsControl. I've created a DataTemplate for this:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNameSpace:Customer}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
            <CheckBox"></CheckBox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Number}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text=" - "></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

So what I want basically is a simple list (with checkboxes) that contains NUMBER - NAME. Isn't there a way in which I can concat the number and name directly in the Binding part?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

There is StringFormat property (in .NET 3.5 SP1), which you probably can use. And usefull WPF binding cheat sheat can found [here](http://www.nbdtech.com/blog/archive/2009/02/02/wpf-xaml-data-binding-cheat-sheet.aspx). 
If it doesn't help, you can allways write your own ValueConverter or custom property for your object.

Just checked, you can use StringFormat with multibinding. In your case code will be something like this:

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} - {1}">
        <Binding Path="Number"/>
        <Binding Path="Name"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

I had to start format string with space, otherwise Visual Studio wouldn't build, but I think you will find way get around it :)

**Edit**
The space is needed in the StringFormat to keep the parser from treating `{0}` as an actual binding. Other alternatives:

```
<!-- use a space before the first format -->
<MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} - {1}">

<!-- escape the formats -->
<MultiBinding StringFormat="\{0\} - \{1\}">

<!-- use {} before the first format -->
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
```

Comment: Instead of the space you can use {}, e.g. StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}"

Comment: You can also escape the braces with backslashes:

<MultiBinding StringFormat="\{0\} - \{1\}">

Comment: Also, the closing TextBlock is missing, so to summarize the comments: <TextBlock >
                                    <TextBlock.Text>
                                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                                            <Binding Path="Number"/>
                                            <Binding Path="Name"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                </TextBlock>

Comment: @PiRX if i want to show 'number' even if 'name' is empty- how do i do that?

Comment: @DasDas unfortunately I won't be able to to help with your question as I haven't worked with WPF for several years. It's funny how fast you forget things you aren't working with anymore.

Comment: Would expanding `StringFormat` to its nested element work without needing to escape things or same trouble?

Answer (score 81):

In case you want to concat a dynamic value with a static text, try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding IndividualSSN, StringFormat= '\{0\} (SSN)'}"/>
```

**Displays**: 234-334-5566 (SSN)

Comment: `ToolTip` not work.

Answer (score 10):

See the following example I used in my code using Run class:

```
        <TextBlock x:Name="..." Width="..." Height="..."
            <Run Text="Area="/>
            <Run Text="{Binding ...}"/>
            <Run Text="sq.mm"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Text="Min Diameter="/>
            <Run Text="{Binding...}"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Text="Max Diameter="/>
            <Run Text="{Binding...}"/>
        </TextBlock >
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a bindable run. Useful stuff, especially if one wants to add some text formatting (colors, fontweight etc.).

```
<TextBlock>
   <something:BindableRun BoundText="{Binding Number}"/>
   <Run Text=" - "/>
   <something:BindableRun BoundText="{Binding Name}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

[Here's](http://fortes.com/2007/03/bindablerun/) an original class: 
[Here](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/01/data_binding_in_a_flowdocument.html) are some additional improvements. 
And that's all in one piece of code:

```
public class BindableRun : Run
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BoundText", typeof(string), typeof(BindableRun), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(BindableRun.onBoundTextChanged)));

        private static void onBoundTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((Run)d).Text = (string)e.NewValue;
        }

        public String BoundText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(BoundTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BoundTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public BindableRun()
            : base()
        {
            Binding b = new Binding("DataContext");
            b.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(FrameworkElement), 1);
            this.SetBinding(DataContextProperty, b);
        }
    }
```

Comment: <Run Text="{Binding...}"/> ? Can you explain the advantages?

Comment: No difference; Run didn't support bindings on the Text property 10 years ago when this answer was written!