# Can we concat two properties in data binding?

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0

Can we concat two properties together in binding expression? If possible without converter or without writing two textblocks and setting them individually?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541896/concatenate-strings-instead-of-using-a-stack-of-textblocks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like alpha-mouse suggests MultiBinding won't work out of the box, but this guy has thrown something together that might help:

http://www.olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/Improvements-to-Silverlight-Multi-binding-support.aspx

If that seems a bit rogue, then *maybe* try putting a combined value property on your object as a helper for the Binding mechanism, like:

```
public string FullName {
   get { return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; }
}
```

Comment: Using `<TextBlock><Run Text="..." /><Run Text="..." /></TextBlock>` is a cleaner XAML-only solution (see the other answer below).

Answer (score 118):

If you want to show, say `FirstName` and `LastName`, in a single `TextBlock`, then you can do like this:

```
<TextBlock>
     <Run Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
     <Run Text="   " /> <!-- space -->
     <Run Text="{Binding LastName}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Now, the TextBlock's `Text` property will be `"Sachin Tendulkar"` and will be displayed if:

```
FirstName = Sachin
LastName  = Tendulkar
```

Comment: You forgot the / before the > in each Run statement. Otherwise, helped me a lot!

Comment: Genius is simplicity!

Comment: Link to documentation: [Run class - UWP reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.run)

Answer (score 32):

```
<TextBlock.Text>
   <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} , {1}">
     <Binding Path="data1" />
     <Binding Path="data2" />
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

data1 and data2 are string properties which are binded.

Comment: This is a great solution, since it will work for more complex components like `DataGrid.TextColumn`.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to add any string, then try it. Here I add "%" after binding text in windows phone.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=clouds.all, StringFormat=\{0\}%}"/>
```

Comment: Works in Maui apps as well:-)

Answer (score 7):

It is possible in WPF with the help of [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) and StringFormat. But not in Silverlight unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a new property with a getter that performs the concatenation.

Say you have `FirstName` and `LastName` properties. You can then define a `Name` property as follows:

```
public string Name { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
```

This will work well, but you should be aware that you cannot do two-way binding for a read-only property. Also you may want to implement property changed notification for the concatenated property in the setters for the source properties.