# Is it possible to add more characters after a binding in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I was wondering something, and couldn't find any relevant topics. I have following binding :

```
Content="{x:Static resx:Resource.Form_OtherOption_Description}"
```

This will place a string in a label. What i was asking myself is if i can add a ":" after that binding, not in code, just in xaml. The label represent something like "Name :". But adding the ":" as part of the binding is not an option.

**Edit**

I'm working in 3.5 version

Any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're in 3.5 you'll most likely need to use @H.B.'s solution.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could accomplish this with something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static resx:Resource.Form_OtherOption_Description},
                         StringFormat={}{0}:}" />
```

**Edit:** `<Label>`s `Content` property does not respect the `StringFormat` property of a binding apparently. Which I've found has been moved to the `ContentStringFormat` property on the `<Label>`.

```
<Label Content="{x:Static resx:Resource.Form_OtherOption_Description}"
       ContentStringFormat="{}{0}:" />
```

Comment: +1, Saw you found the answer as well :) So `ContentControl` has `ContentStringFormat`, `HeaderedContentControl` has `HeaderStringFormat`, and `ItemsControl` has `ItemStringFormat`. Good to know

Comment: Appears that `Label.Content` does not pick up the `StringFormat` from the binding because the `TargetType` is not `string`, but instead `object`. In the case of `TextBlock.Text`, the target type is `string`, and thus it is used in the binding.

Comment: Good spot - although not as elegent you can add a TextBlock to the labels content, but this would be additional overhead.

Answer (score 22):

If you're using WPF 4.0, you could also do this:

```
<TextBlock>
       <Run Text="{Binding SomeLabel}"/>
       <Run Text=":"/>
</TextBlock>
```

This actually concatenates the two strings coming from two `Run` tag and copied into `TextBlock.Text` property!.

Using this approach you can even bind to different properties in presenter, and display it in a single `TexBlock`. See this excellent example:

[Can we concat two properties in data binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325453/can-we-concat-two-properties-in-data-binding/4327843#4327843)

Answer (score 10):

You can also use MultiBinding with StringFormat e.g:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="ID {0} Name: {1} Age: {2}">
            <Binding Source="{x:Static resx:SomeResx.ID}"/>
             <Binding Path="Name"/>
             <Binding Path="Age"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

You can use this in a content control TextBlock TextBlock.Text (sorry I couldn't get the code to show up for this above)

Comment: As per sixlettervariables answer above the label uses a contentStringFormat. To get the above multibindings to work with a label assign the TextBlock to its content.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. Here I add "testing" after binding text(clouds.all) in windows phone.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=clouds.all, StringFormat=\{0\}testing}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Binding's property [StringFormat](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/29/trying-out-binding-stringformat.aspx) - it can do very simply what you want.

Answer (score 2):

if you use a label inside a progress bar you can use this way:

```
<Label x:Name="Progress" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Opacity=".7" 
       Content="{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0}%">
```

in this way you can visualize the value of progressbar with a % added.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a converter that takes the input string and adds the ":".

```
public class AddStringToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string input = value as string;
        string suffix = parameter as string;

        return input + suffix;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:AddStringToStringConverter x:Key="AddStringToStringConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Static resx:Resource.Form_OtherOption_Description}, Converter={StaticResource AddStringToStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=:}"/>
```

Or something like that. Tried it and it worked for my source at least.

If you have whitespace and the like in you `ConverterParameter` you can use signle quotes to make sure it does not get disposed.

**Edit:** Oh right... yeah... there's also `StringFormat` which i have never needed before, ehehehe...