# Add Additional Character in WPF Data Bind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I'm new in WPF application and i have a question.

Is it possible to add additional character for each row bind from database?

I've drag and drop dataset to create a list of datagrid. It will automatically generate codes for data binding.
I want to add '%' symbol on the back of {Percentage} data.

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="percentageColumn" Binding="{Percentage}" Header="Percentage" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
```

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947395/is-it-possible-to-add-more-characters-after-a-binding-in-xaml/37521312) kinda confuse me a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example answers it perfectly. Just use stringformat with the binding.

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="percentageColumn" Binding="{Percentage,StringFormat={}{0}%}" Header="Percentage" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
```

Comment: Oh, i thought i should add after Binding tag. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'DataGridTextColumn', you can use 'DataGridTemplateColumn' to achieve your requirement like below and you can append whatever string next to your percentage value.

```
`<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Percentage">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                        
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                               
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Percentage}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" %"/>
                        </StackPanel>                            
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>`
```

Comment: What the differences between those 2? And which one is more preferable?