# concatenate strings in rowheader - xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, concatenation, datagridrowheader

My problem is as follows: I have a datagrid that is bound to my datatable. I want a `Button` to be placed in the row header, and I want the `Button.Content` to display the concatenate of two strings. I have tried combining these two solutions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791929/wpf-datagrid-rowheader-databinding) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541896/concatenate-strings-instead-of-using-a-stack-of-textblocks)

I have success with each individually, but combined it yields a blank `Button.Content`. Here's what I've tried

```
                   <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Width="90">
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} - {1}">
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}" Path="Item.Index"/>
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}" Path="Item.Category"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Button.Content>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `TextBlock` and binding its `Text` property:

```
<Button Width="90">
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} - {1}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}" Path="Item.Index"/>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}" Path="Item.Category"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

`StringFormat` only applies if target is a `string` property

Answer (score 0):

I think your StringFormat syntax is wrong : try :

```
 <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
      <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}" Path="Item.Index"/>
      <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}" Path="Item.Category"/>
 </MultiBinding>
```

Comment: According to the article I pointed to in the question, either way is acceptable