# Listbox selection change not firing on click on child in list box item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, listboxitem

I have a wpf user control which contains a Listbox which is binded to my View Model. Each Listbox item is consists of three textblock. I made the UI in a way that when user clicks on the Frist TextBlock(Title) function in my View Model will get called.

To uniquely Identify the ListBox item corresponding to which text block now got clicked. I added another property in my view model which is bindied to SelectionChanged Event in the Listbox. So whenever my TextBlock binded command get exectuted I will use my SelectionChanged Property to find which List Box Item and use its data context.

But the issue I am facing now is that when User clicks on the First textblock, selectionchanged event is not firing. When User clicks outside the First Textblock only Selection Changed event is getting fired. Which made my view model to process wrong list box items.

Following is the XAML snippet.

```
                <ListBox ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNotificationItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyArray}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource HoverBackgroundStyle}"  Name="NotificationListBox" >
                 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Border BorderThickness="4,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{Binding ColorThing, Converter={StaticResource SeverityToColorConverter} }" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">
                                <StackPanel Margin="8, 0" Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock   Style="{StaticResource HoverUnderlineStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Name="Title" Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="0,4,0,0" >
                                        <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                                            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ClickTitleCommand}"></MouseBinding>
                                        </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                                    </TextBlock>

                                    <TextBlock  FontWeight="Normal" Name="Desc" Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">

                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock  FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="Gray" Name="Date" Text="{Binding CreationTime, StringFormat={}{0:ddd MM.dd.yyyy} }" Margin="0,4,0,4">
                                    </TextBlock>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to find the `ListBox item` (i.e. a UI component), or are you interested in which object within your `ItemsSource` is the item clicked on? If the latter, why not just use your existing `SelectedItem` binding to detect the change?

Comment: But to answer your question, I'd suspect `SelectionChanged` isn't firing because the selection isn't actually changing: that first entry was already selected, either automatically or because of your `SelectedItem` binding.

Comment: I am interested in the object within my ItemSource only.The issue is selectedItem is not firing if we click on the First Text Block, which has a Mouse Binding.So I am unable to find it.

Comment: In that case, your `SelectedItem` binding will already hold the item you're interested in. If you want to detect when that changes then call your handling code in the setter of your `SelectedNotificationItem` property. When you first start your app, are you setting `SelectedNotificationItem` to anything, or is it null? Are you seeing any binding errors in your VS output window?

Comment: In my application (which is a package), I am not setting anything to my SelectedNotificationItem. When debugged found its null. And the issue is when I click the first time on the Title Textblock. My  comamnd ClickTitleCommand will get called and When I checked the SelectedNotificationItem from my command its null... I don't need to call my function when user clicks on the list box item I need only when user clikcs on the first text block.

Comment: When I click on the list box item, then selectionchanged event is firing and my binded variable is working fine.

Comment: In that case I would suspect that your `MouseAction` input binding is swallowing the SelectionChanged: do you notice that when you click your textbox the selection for the row doesn't change (i.e. the colour change normally associated with clicking a row doesn't happen)? That being the case, an alternative would be to add a CommandParameter to this `ClickTitleCommand` that passes in the item for that row (`CommandParameter="{Binding }"`) and then you should know which item was clicked on, and could also change the selected item at that point if you desire.

Comment: Yes thanks I did in that way.. Added Parameter :  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" and working

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing your XAML to `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNotificationItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: Instead of using several textblocks in one stackpanel, please consider using MultiBinding. See the link below:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541896/concatenate-strings-instead-of-using-a-stack-of-textblocks

Comment: I was looking forward to dynamically change some property in the second textblock. All text block should act differently. If multi binding this might be possible ?

Comment: Hi Ted, If you are talking about StringFormat then yes, it is possible. You can have StringFormat for the whole multibinding or the single Binding where required.

Comment: Nope May be dynacmically change the content of textblock2 and textblock3 or the size of the textblocks.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Change the ListBox into an *ItemsControl* and change the orientation to *horizontal*

Comment: How it will fix the firing of events ?

Comment: I don't think this answer is helpful, nor does it really explain.