# Concatenate String with Bindings XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, binding

Is it possible to have some static text and a bindable context in the same label?

```
<Label Text = "${Binding totalCost}"
       x:Name = "totalCost"
       HorizontalOptions = "Start"
       VerticalOptions = "Start"
       Grid.Row = "6" Grid.Column = "1"/>
```

Except this displays as "${Binding totalCost}"

I know I could just easily set the field by doing something like `totalCost.Text = String.Format("${0}", totalCost);` but just wanted to see if it was possible the other way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate strings instead of using a stack of TextBlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541896/concatenate-strings-instead-of-using-a-stack-of-textblocks)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
Text="{Binding totalCost, StringFormat=${0}}"
```

Comment: Thank you! That did in fact work for me. I will accept your answer in 5 minutes when it allows me to.

Comment: This is wonderful. Working in WPF core as well.

Answer (score 10):

For labels there is additional feature: ContentStringFormat, example bellow:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Tag, FallbackValue=Custom}" ContentStringFormat="Length: {0}" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cbRebarLength, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Although the selected answer is correct, you will be ignoring commas in your currency values or the potential period. A better way would be to expose a get property that provides the appropriate value for the binding. Below is a code snippet for anyone in the future

```
<Label Text = "${Binding TotalCostFormatted}"
      x:Name = "totalCost"
      HorizontalOptions = "Start"
      VerticalOptions = "Start"
      Grid.Row = "6" Grid.Column = "1"/>
```

In your ViewModel

```
double totalCost;
public double TotalCost 
{
    get { return totalCost; }
    set 
    {
        totalCost = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalCostFormatted));
    }
}
public string TotalCostFormatted
{
    get { return TotalCost.ToString("C0"); } 
}
```

Remember you can always just create a `get` property in your `ViewModel` that exposes some data. Call `OnPropertyChanged` or whatever your method is called that implements your `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. If you want the cents on your dollar value, change "C0" to just "C".

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking the .NET way of doing what you want, which is format value string as currency, is using the binding property `StringFormat` along with the [Currency Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-currency-c-format-specifier):

```
Text="{Binding totalCost, StringFormat=\{0:C\}}"
```

Your code would look like this

```
<Label Text="{Binding totalCost, StringFormat=\{0:C\}}"
   x:Name = "totalCost"
   HorizontalOptions = "Start"
   VerticalOptions = "Start"
   Grid.Row = "6"
   Grid.Column = "1"/>
```

Cheers.