# In WPF XAML, How to Bind two properties in a textblock using datatrigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

How can i bind two properties in textblock using datatrigger in wpf xaml ?
Below is my XAML Code

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
     <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
          <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StkTypeValue}" Value="Y">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding AvailableQty }" />
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding PrimaryUM}" />
             </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
   </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate strings instead of using a stack of TextBlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541896/concatenate-strings-instead-of-using-a-stack-of-textblocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `MultiBinding` and `IMultiValueConverter` for this purpose:
**Try this:**

```
<TextBlock.Style>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
          <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StkTypeValue}" Value="Y">
                   <Setter Property="Text">
                   <Setter.Value>
                      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource textMultiBindingConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="AvailableQty " />
                        <Binding Path="PrimaryUM"/>
                      </MultiBinding>
                   </Setter.Value>
                 </Setter>
             </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

Define `Converter` as Resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TextMultiBindingConverter x:Key="textMultiBindingConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And Your `Converter`:

```
class TextMultiBindingConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (values[0].ToString() + values[1].ToString());
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot convert back");
    }
}
```

Comment: how to write converter textMultiBindingConverter ?

Comment: Marked as a Answer .. Thanks once again

Comment: what about the fact, that this question is a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541896/concatenate-strings-instead-of-using-a-stack-of-textblocks

Comment: Hi tabby , Can yu help me in this ? 
How to write triggers for telerik:GridViewDataColumn ?

Comment: Ask a new question and see if its not asked previously

Comment: @pix by the time i see your Link as a duplicate, i already answered. and my answer is totally different from the existing one

Comment: I cannot ask question for next few days

Comment: Add a trigger inside your telerik:GridViewDataColumn datatemplate or inside your telerik:RadGridView style... there is plenty of way to do it. And google is really helpfull -> http://www.telerik.com/forums/style-triggers-or-datatemplate-triggers

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to show both values when the DataTrigger is activated. If true you can use MultiBinding with StringFormat:

```
<TextBlock.Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StkTypeValue}" Value="Y">
            <Setter Property="Text">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                        <Binding Path="AvailableQty" />
                        <Binding Path="PrimaryUM" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```